Please help me generalize this question! :)
Original question: How does a near decade of non-treatment affect what a doctor prescribes?
Comment:
How for example to generalize? Basically someone gets diagnosed as a child and is recommended something. It gets ignored for 8-9 years. Teen/young adult has problems and then finally gets treated. Likely, the recommended treatment for the teen/young adult is different for the recommendation for the child.
